# How to loop through list and add images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I have an array of artifacts with 6 images.

```
var artifacts = [
  'http://placehold.it/50x150',
  'http://placehold.it/100x125',
  'http://placehold.it/150x100',
  'http://placehold.it/200x50',
  'http://placehold.it/150x75',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100'
];
```

I am trying to add a artifact as a background-image to every list-item in the list.

```
<ul class="slick-dots">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

If the list has more than the amount of artifacts it will start in the beginning and add the artifact in the [0] position of the array.

For some reason, I can't wrap my head around how I should approach this with javascript.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/MJYgdz

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: Loop through your list of `li` elements. Keep a separate counter for you image array. When the counter reaches the end of the array reset it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method with callback which iterates internally. Where the first argument is index and based on that get value from the array to generate css property value.

```js
var artifacts = [
  'http://placehold.it/50x150',
  'http://placehold.it/100x125',
  'http://placehold.it/150x100',
  'http://placehold.it/200x50',
  'http://placehold.it/150x75',
  'http://placehold.it/100x100'
];

$('ul.slick-dots li').css('background-image', function(i) {
  return "url('" + artifacts[i % artifacts.length] + "')";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slick-dots">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow! That's efficient, does the trick just fine. 
Can you explain how this works? I'm confused regarding the '%'

Thank you!

Comment: @h0bb5 : where `i` refers to the element index..... so `i % artifacts.length` would be used to calculate the index..... which calculates the remainder (wich is in the range or array index `0,1,......,arrayLength-1`) ...... if index reached to `arrayLength` =>  `i % artifacts.length` results `0`,  `arrayLength + 1` =>  `i % artifacts.length` results `1`.... and so on